# android- AVD No target selected when I want to create android 4.4

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I get latest version of android api 4.4 (api19) .

When I want to make a new virtual device , I select Android 4.4.2- api level 19 . like the image below  ;
[image]

It says no target selected and I can't make it .I've maked several other devices with no problem , but could make this one .

this is the image of my SDK :
[image]

is there anything missing ? What is the problem ?

thanks you

Comment: Do you have installed the images as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Possible reason for Error:

[image]

### Solution:

**Step1**: `Start your AVD`

**Step2**: `Download the image and install it`

**Step3**: `Restart the Eclipse`

Answer (score 0):

You have missed installing the

**ARM EABI v7a System Image**
or 
**Intel x86 Atom System image** under Android 4.4.2 using sdk manager .

Install and then select one ARM or Intel to create your AVD.

Answer (score 0):

In your AVD ,you have missed to fill the details in CPU/ABI .
It is missing . You should use the SDK manager to install the appropriate image for the SDK version you are using. You simply need to check the ARM image in the SDK manager and click Install.

Name: Nexus7

Target: Android 4.4 (API level 19)

CPU/ ABI: armeabi-v7a

Skin: 800x1280